# Prove $b^{c- a}\geq a^{c- b}c^{b- a}$

Tags: inequality

I want to prove:

For $a, b, c>0$ and $a\leq  b\leq  c$ then $b^{c- a}\geq  a^{c- b}c^{b- a}$

From this inequality, I can prove the under inequality easily: $$a_{1}x_{1}+ a_{2}x_{2}\geq  x_{1}^{a_{1}}+ x_{2}^{a_{2}}$$ with $x_{1}+ x_{2}= 1$

I try to use logarithm two both sides but I can' t

Thus, I need to the help, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We will examine our inequality by take the logarithm both sides:
$$\log b\ge \frac{c-b}{c-a}\log a + \frac{b-a}{c-a}\log c. $$

Now observe that
$$\frac{c-b}{c-a} a + \frac{b-a}{c-a} c = b.$$
Therefore, as logarithm is [concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function), our inequality directly follows.

Comment: Yes. The case $c=a$ is obvious.